# SublimeText - typing "html" + {TAB} just returns HTML, not full default tags

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I just installed Emmet, and when I type `html` <kbd>TAB</kbd> I only get

```
<html></html>
```

Before then, when I did so, Sublimetext would create all the default tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a setting or something I can update in Emmet, or Sublime text so that when I have Emmet enabled, I can get the "full" tags?

The file is a `.html` file, and it's set to HTML in Sublime.

Here's a quick .gif - I start with Emmet diabled:

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting up the filetype to HTML? If not, open comman prompt (typically Ctrl + ⇧ + P) and type HTML. Select "Set Syntax : HTML". After that things should work fine.

Another option is just to save the file with html extension and then try again.

Comment: @Garbage - Yeah, it's set to `HTML` (bottom right), and is already a .html file.

Comment: Oh, alright. May be try in another window/new file and see if it's sublime text problem or just that particular file?

Comment: @Garbage - It does it in a new file too - just gives `<html></html>`.  I notice that you can do things like type `strong` and hit `TAB`, and it creates `<strong></strong>` automatically, without Emmet installed. I'm guessing with Emmet enabled, it's taking the more "simple" route and just returning the `<html></html>` without using the "shortcut" that SublimeText has specifically for that tag? (does that make sense?)

Comment: umm.. Does it need Emmet BTW? IIRC, the html template works in Sublime without Emmet.

Comment: @Garbage - I like some of the features Emmet has, so thought to use it.  I can, as the .gif shows, just disable it, do the HTML tag loading, then enable it, but that's a little much I think - I'm curious why enabling Emmet "removes" that feature.

Comment: related https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/html-tab-does-nothing/18464/34

Comment: @Oleg - Ah! `html:5` + `TAB` does the trick!  Feel free to post that as the answer, thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **Sublime Text 3** it's

`html:5` + <kbd>tab</kbd>

**Returns:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text 3 you can type `<h`, and you will get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Also you should make document type HTML

Answer (score 0):

on mine, html + TAB gives me what you're getting, but if I do html + ENTER, then I get the entire boilerplate.